# Google sheets formula - how to change the value in one cell, depending on the values entered in a row range

Tags: google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

In Google Sheets I have a row of values (0 or 1). I want to put a formula in the next column which changes the value in that cell from 1 to 0 if any of the values in the other cells in the same row are equal to 1. What formula would do this?

I have tried IF, SUMIF, COUNT, ARRAY but none of them seem to work and clearly, I am no expert!

Comment: what did you try with those functions? something *like* `=IF(COUNTIF(....that row...,0);"some 0 found";"all ones")` could work as far as I can tell (may require syntax cleanup, but the idea is counting zeroes in the row, and use IF to differentiate result based on if there's some zero or none)

Comment: Thanks for the replies: the spreadsheet has a row of data across several 'categories of information' columns. A 1 in a cell indicates that there is some info about X in a document; a 0 indicates that there is no info about X in said document. Each row is a different document.  The final column/cell in the row looks at the preceding range of values (0 or 1). If there are any 1s in the range, the value in the final cell changes to 0; if there are no 1's in the row range, the value remains 1 ).  PS how do I link  a sample sheet to this question?

Comment: where do I create the sample spreadsheet - your previous post has disappeared!

Comment: [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14j_5VfaUhDEbTIRmss54YKFceaFcTbHrQqrka8WdluY/edit#gid=953131243

Comment: Added formula in the test sheet. do test it out.

Comment: Thanks so much - that seems to work and I would never have come up with that. There seem to be 3 solutions so  thanks for all of them!

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=byrow(C2:F,lambda(Σ,if(count(Σ),if(sum(Σ)=0,1,0),)))
```

[image]